# Assume role for elasticsearch on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have some lambda functions sending logs to my Elastic search cluster from AWS and it work great.
Lambda function have the following role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:*:<ACCOUNT_ID>:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But now i want to setup my own elastic search running on an ec2 instance, so i can install X-Pack along with Kibana.

How can I let my lambda function posting logs to my custom elastic search?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: May I ask why would you want to do that? AWS managed elasticsearch saves a lot of headache.

Comment: @johni in the question: install X-Pack along with Kibana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will be running your own elasticsearch instance on an ec2 machine, and you want to enable access from lambda, you wont need any IAM access policies.

If your lambda function is running in default configuration, (No VPC), its has access to internet. So any URL it must access must be public. You must assign a public IP to your EC2 instace, and expose port 9200 or whichever through your security group.

I would not recommend this approach though as it exposes your elasticsearch to the world.

You need to run your lambda function from a VPC and enable access to the elasticsearch cluster for the CIDR range of your subnet in which the lambda will be running.

For Kibana to work, you need to add another rule in your security group to enable access to port 9200 from select IP addresses for eg. your workplace.

Comment: so the only way is via security groups? Basically running a lambda function inside a VPC and exiting via a nat gateway with elastic IP. This way, knowing my elastic IP, i can filter my ec2 instance to elastic_ip:9200. Ok thanks for your idea :)  i'm not too happy having to do it this way though, but i will give it a try.

Comment: "Basically running a lambda function inside a VPC and exiting via a nat gateway with elastic IP. This way, knowing my elastic IP, i can filter my ec2 instance to elastic_ip:9200": When a lambda function runs inside a VPC, you need to provide the subnets in which he lambda function can run. If the subnet is private and your ec2 instances are part of the same subnet, the only thing you will need to do is allow lambda 9200 to be accessible from the security group for the subnet. ElasticIP is not needed. I know this is a lot of work, but you pay the price of customization.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have 4 lambda functions in 4 different account and my elastic search is inside a special account for logs aggregation, so no much joy ;/